# Synonym of Python set class in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, set

In python I can do something like this:

```
s = set()
s.add(1)
s.add(1) # this doesn't change set
assert 1 in s # check that set contains 1
assert not 2 in s # check that set doesn't contains 2
```

What is synonym for this code in Java(I expect it should works only for one predefined type)?

Comment: You should probably look int the `Set` interface, and `HashSet` class in particular: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java this could be written:

```
Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
s.add(1);
s.add(1); // this doesn't change set
assert s.contains(1); // check that set contains 1
assert !s.contains(2); // check that set doesn't contain 2
```

Note: You would need to run Java with the `-ea` switch to enable assertions.

Comment: I hate java for absence of default assertions:)

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing the asserts to do unit testing, you could use [JUnit](http://junit.org/). A framework to do precisely this.

```
@org.junit.Test
public void testSet() {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    set.add(1);
    set.add(1);

    org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(set.contains(1));
    org.junit.Assert.assertFalse(set.contains(2));
}
```